# Java module as dependency for both an Android-Gradle Module and a Non-Gradle Java Module using IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, build, android-gradle-plugin

I am working in IntelliJ IDEA, and I have the following components:

1) An android gradle library module

2) A non-gradle java-based webapp

3) A non-gradle java module that has basic classes, that I'd like to share with both (1) and (2) above.

The problem is that IntelliJ does not allow a project to contain both Android-Gradle modules and non-Gradle Java modules in the same project. So putting them all together then linking via module dependencies is a non-starter.

IntelliJ error message:
"Unfortunately you can't have non-Gradle Java modules and Android-Gradle modules in one project."

So how can I share the dependency (3) between (1) and (2)?

Comment: Could you not just build it as a library, host the jar on a local (on your machine or a company server or some such) maven repository and add it to your gradle build file??

Comment: You mean build (3) into a jar, then pull the jar into (1) and (2)?

Comment: Yeah.  You will probably have to manage it in a different intelliJ project though.

Comment: Gotcha. I suppose that is possible. However, it is a bit cumbersome. Would have to rebuild / redistribute the jar into the projects every time I updated anything in it. I'm hoping there is an easier way.

Comment: Hi, have you managed to find a solution for this ?